# How to fix font color in PDI? currently all font is white

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

[image: heres a sample pic of my pdi with all text color in white]

I have a version 9.1 installed in my local machine with macos 11.1

Need help in making the font color to black.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify @Michal's answer, starting from 9.3 you can use dark mode along with pdi basically.

Since I have to switched to light mode to indicate the right position, there is a step by step for blind touching like me.

Preferences -> Second tab (Look & Feel) -> Use look of OS (3rd row from bottom)

[image]

Comment: me on linux:

Tools -> Options -> Look & Feel -> Use look of OS

Answer (score 3):

Just found out the answer. Dont put your mac's appearance to dark mode.
When i change it back to light mode, all texts in pdi became black.
Just close pentaho and open again after changing to light mode.

Answer (score 1):

In version 9.3, there is a checkbox Use look of OS (3rd row from bottom, 2nd checkbox from bottom - for those, who are lazy to switch to dark mode) in Preferences - Look & Feel. After checking it, you can still use Dark mode in OS with black texts in PDI.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no mode to solve this but i have one quick solution for you.

1. Install the app "Night Owl" this app let's you to switch between dark and light mode from the tray.

Kind regards,

Comment: Link to NightOwl: https://nightowl.kramser.xyz/#slider